# How to also attach folder and not just file to the SharePoint List item?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-item

I was wondering if there is any way of attaching folders to the SharePoint List item?

As far as I know, we can attach documents but we can not attach folders, is there any way of achieving this?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible unfortunately. You may be able to create a Hyperlink column and link to folders stored in a document library however.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Callum Crowley's point of view. Usually document libraries are used to store attachments.

You could also refer to [this article](https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-lists-vs-libraries/) for more information about lists and libraries.